# Faster: SWT or Java2D?

Tags: swt, java-2d

Which has faster graphics performance: SWT or Java2D?

On MacOSX, Does SWT's graphics go through Quartz Extreme which in turn is rendered using hardware-accelerated OpenGL?

I'm not referring to the native UI controls but asking about custom 2D graphics rendering like text, lines, curves and polygons.

Answer (score 3):

### Both Use The Platform's Graphics API

Java Swing and SWT take opposite approaches.

Java Swing uses Java2D both to draw its widgets and for custom drawing, which is a cross-platform graphics api which abstracts the underlying platform's graphics api. Now Java2D's performance depends on the performance & efficiency of the Platform's Native API.

SWT uses the platform's native graphics API for custom drawing and uses the platform's native GUI API (if present) for drawing its widgets. Now the point to be noted is, that for most platforms the GUI API itself uses the platform's graphics API for drawing the widgets.

### Graphical Representation

[image: All Depends on the Graphics API]

---

As you can see, ultimately all depend's on the Platform's Graphics API. So both offer more-or-less the same performance & speed.

### Some Exceptions

There are some exceptions, that may or may not affect performance.

- Java Swing uses pure Java code as much as it can, this may give it a performance boost.
- On some platforms Java2D may use a better, faster API in addition to the platform's default, for example it supports Direct3D on Windows.
- The native code that SWT relies on may prove to be faster in some cases, than using the Java2D abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

I theory, SWT should be faster since it directly uses native UI implementations.

But in practice, it all depends on SWT and SWING implementations on each platform.

In my experience, SWT is faster in Windows, but it is not faster on Mac OS X.

Comment: Are you using only SWT controls/widgets? Or do you use it to do custom drawing?